# How to exclude resource file from quarkus fast jar

Tags: quarkus

I have a sql file under directory src/main/resources/db/migration/V1.0.0_Quarkus.sql.

I want to exclude this file from being packaged into the fast jar and provide a path to a file on a filesystem during deployment.

Below guide mentions about excluding the file from uber-jar and not the fast-jar.
I want to use fast-jar and exclude certain resource files being packaged.
How to do this?

https://quarkus.io/guides/maven-tooling#build-tool-maven

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by configuring:

`quarkus.class-loading.removed-resources."groupID\:artifactID"=db/migration/V1.0.0_Quarkus.sql`

in `application.properties`

Make sure `groupID` and `artifactID` are substituted with the proper values (you can also configure Maven to set these - see [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html))

Comment: added the config , but the jar still contains the files